# BizTalk 2013 R2 installation

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013r2

While installing BizTalk Server 2013 R2, when I try to check the component "Developer tools & SDK" it appears as an unavailable. I get the message "At least one of the requirements for this option is not installed or it doesn't met"

Could you please tell me why this option is unavailable? Do I need to install any other component before?

I am following the steps that I found at [BizTalk 2013 Installation and Configuration – Install and Configure BizTalk Server 2013 (Part 9)](https://sandroaspbiztalkblog.wordpress.com/2013/05/16/biztalk-2013-installation-and-configuration-install-and-configure-biztalk-server-2013-part-9/)

Answer (score 3):

Ok here are all your possible installation scenarios :

1. You are installing BizTalk Server (whatever version) to make a Build Server 
   =>Then yes you need Visual Studio to be able to install Developer tools & SDK,
    those packages contains MSBuild & other stuff that enable you to build & deploy an app
2. You are installing BizTalk Server as a "real" Server (Prod, Integration...) 
   => You don't need developer tools & SDK
3. You are installing BizTalk Server on a Dev Machine 
   => you are supposed to already have a Visual Studio installed

Answer (score 3):

**BizTalk 2013 /2013 R2 Project Templates with Visual Studio 2015**

[image: BizTalk 2013 /2013 R2 Project Templates with Visual Studio 2015]
Yes, the Setup of the BizTalk 2013 requires for the feature 'Developer tools & SDK' per default Visual Studio 2012, and the Setup of BizTalk 2013 R2 Visual Studio 2013, otherwise the feature is disabled.

Frustrated with this fact (at work we have now upgraded to VS2015), I now find a way to install the templates under VS 2015 and without an installation of VS2012/ 2013 at the system.

Tool required: Orca to modify the msi.

Files to modify are located in subdir MSI of the BTServer dir of the extracted ISO (make a backup of these files!)

Installations to modify:
Microsoft BizTalk Server.msi and 
Microsoft BizTalk Server64.msi

Modifications:
AppSearch-Table: Drop Row for the property 'CSHARP_INSTALLED'
Properties-Table: Add Row, property Name = 'CSHARP_INSTALLED', Value = 'True'
Properties-Table: Set the value of the property 'TargetVsVersion' to '14.0'

Do this for both MSI's, save.

Now, the Prerequirement VS 2012/ 2013 from the files
Setup.xml and
Setup_64.xml must be removed.

Simple remove the entry
    `<RequiredComponent Name="VS2012"/>` or 
    `<RequiredComponent Name="VS2013"/>` 
from the node
    `<Feature Name="Development">`
DONE!

---EDIT
If someone has a valid RegKey to check if VS215 is installed, the Check in the Setup.xml can rewritten to this. This would be nice and valid
One valid modified Search for a Visual Studio 2015 installation could be:

```
<!-- language: lang-xml -->
<PlatformComponent _locAttrData="DisplayName" _locID="25" Name="VS2015" DisplayName="Microsoft Visual Studio 2015">
<Detection Type="RegDWORD">
    <DetectKey Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\Setup\Visual Studio 2015 Prerequisites" Value="InstallSuccess" ValueData="1"/>
</Detection>
```

Comment: Followed these instructions on a Windows 10 virtual machine with VisualStudio 2015 installed and it worked great!

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio 2013 is a software requirement for BizTalk Server 2013 R2 Developer Tools and SDK.

More info: [Hardware and Software Requirements for BizTalk Server 2013 and 2013 R2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj248697.aspx)